# Using val() to send data to a input field when page has loaded. When I save it it saves the contact info to the customer field also

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My script adds the data to the html contact field below according to what is selected from the customer field. But when I save the data it saves what is in the contact field in the customer field also. How can I stop this from happening

```
function updateValue()
{
    $('#contact').val($('#customer').val());
}
//update once the page has loaded too
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateValue();
});



<select name="customer"id="customer" class="responsetext1" onchange="updateValue();" >

<input name="contact"  id="contact">
```

The falling script are how the drop down gets its data for the customer field

```
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
$.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "signing.php",
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
        success: function(response){                    
            $(".responsesign").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    }); 
});


<?php
include("connect.php");
$id = $_SESSION['profile']['id'];
echo "<option value=''>SELECT A SIGNING</option>";
foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM signings WHERE pid = '$id' AND done = 0") as $row) {

   echo "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" .$row['ordern']. "   " .$row['lname'] . "    </option>";
 }
```

This is the ajax script that sends the data to the php script to save the data from the form

```
// JavaScript Document
$("#sub").click( function(event) {
 //stop the click event from bubbling
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
       function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
  return false; // at end  
   });
 clearInput();
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});

function clearInput() {
 $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
    $(this).val('');
 });
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the values of `#contact` and `#customer` swap? I'm sorry if I'm not understanding what is happening.

Comment: Can you please mention your save script.